# anyone get mysql workbench 5.2 to work with mamp?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i cannot get mysql workbench 5.2 to work. i have mamp and mamp pro installed and running and no matter what type of connection i try it just wont connect. what can i do?

i have a mac with snow leopard

Answer (score 7):

In MySQL workbench use Connection Method: Local Connection/Pipe and in the setting Socket/Pipe path enter: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock then enter your root username/password.

Answer (score 2):

There are two tasks that need to be fixed to get MySQL Workbench working with a MAMP installation:

1) The Start/Stop/Status commands for the MySql server need to changed from the Server Instance configuration to the following:

Set the Start MySQL command to:
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh`

Set the Stop MySQL command to:
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh`

Set the Check MySQL Status command to:
`ps xa | grep "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/[m]ysqld"`

2) The my.cnf file needs to be created manually and the appropriate permissions given through a terminal window:

Utilities -> Terminal

```
sudo touch /etc/my.cnf
sudo chown joeb /etc/my.cnf
```

- Changed joeb with your username.

If you want a more detailed guide, see [MAMP, MySQL Workbench, WordPress installation and setup guide for MAC](http://frankieinguanez.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/mamp-mysql-workbench-wordpress-installation-and-setup-guide-for-mac/).

Answer (score 0):

I follwed these instructions and got it to work: http://chrischarlton.us/tip/using-mysql-workbench-mamp-pro